# Declarative Jenkins with WithCredentials and Powershell

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

```
stage('Deployment') {
steps {
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'Test', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
        powershell '$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "${PASSWORD}" -Force'
        powershell '$SecureString = "${pass}"'
        powershell '$MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "${USERNAME}","${SecureString}"'
        powershell 'New-PSSession -ComputerName 192.123.123.123 -Credential "${MySecureCreds}"'
     }
     powershell 'Copy-Item "${ARTIFACT_PATH}" -Destination "${DESTINATION_PATH}" -ToSession -Recurse -Force'
     powershell 'Start-Process "iisreset.exe" -NoNewWindow -Wait'
     powershell 'Remove-Website -Name WebCareRecord'
     powershell 'Remove-WebAppPool WebCareRecord'
     powershell 'Get-WebBinding -Port 85 -Name WebCareRecord | Remove-WebBinding'
     powershell 'Start-Process "iisreset.exe" -NoNewWindow -Wait'
     powershell 'New-WebAppPool -Name WebCareRecord'
     powershell 'Set-ItemProperty "${POOL_PATH}" managedPipelineMode 0'
     powershell 'Set-ItemProperty "${POOL_PATH}" managedRuntimeVersion ""'
     powershell 'New-WebSite -Name WebCareRecord -Port 85 -PhysicalPath "${PHYSICAL_PATH}" -ApplicationPool WebCareRecord'
     powershell 'Start-Process "iisreset.exe" -NoNewWindow -Wait'
 }
}
```

I am trying to get the Jenkins credentials ID, secure it and use the same credentials to login into the remote server. After login to the remote server, copy the artifact from jenkins server to remote server. For this I am getting error

org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.CredentialNotFoundException: Credentials 'Test' is of type 'Username with password' where 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.StringCredentials' was expected.

Comment: Is the user you use an admin user? I had this too and I suspect its the call in the credentials plugin which is not whitelisted in script security plugin. The actual error is a cleaned up exception, as far as I found

Comment: Yes the user I am using is an admin user.

Comment: I don't think you are getting groovy variable inside step ```powershell 'with single quotes'```, however I am also having trouble with double quotes as then I am unable to create powershell variables as they produce groovy exceptions ```groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: userpass for class: groovy.lang.Binding```. Here I was trying to do ```powershell "$userpass = new-object.."```

Comment: Did we get any answer for this @Spidy?

Answer (score 3):

There might be multiple problems, I'm going through similar process now and feeling the pain to get it correctly in powershell within groovy, so this is what I've noticed so far:

You are creating a `$pass` variable in one powershell step, and then trying to access it in another powershell step, I don't think it will work that way, as another step  might launch in different powershell session and that powershell variable is no longer there.

I would try something like this:

```java
stage('Deployment') {
  steps {
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'Test', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
        powershell """
          \$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $PASSWORD -Force
          \$SecureString = \$pass
        """
    }
  }
}
```

First, use multiline syntax `"""` so the different powershell statements are in the same session, and those variables are available across powershell commands.

Second, you escape powershell variables `\$pass` and `\$SecureString`, so groovy does not try to expand them, and you don't escape variables where you are actually referring to groovy variables like `$PASSWORD`.
Note that `$PASSWORD` does not have to be in quotes, since powershell parameters can accept strings without quotes, but if this was used in a method you should put it into quotes `SomePowershellMethod("$GROOVYVAR")`.

In general I suggest to echo every variable while troubleshooting, to see if you are getting what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

I like short and precise answer.

Use following :

```
stage('Deployment') {
        steps {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'UatServer', passwordVariable: 'passVar', usernameVariable: 'userVar')]) {
                powershell '''
                    $passVar = ConvertTo-SecureString "$($ENV:passVar)" -AsPlainText -Force
                    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$ENV:userVar", $passVar)
                    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName x.x.x.x -Credential $credential
                    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {hostname}
                '''
            }
            
        }
    }
```